# Configuring grub for Ubuntu on Lenovo Ideapad Flex 10

Tags: grub2, uefi, bootloader

**Situation**

I have installed Ubuntu Linux 14.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 10. The only problem I'm facing now is to configure the bootloader. I'm quite familiar with Ubuntu, but not with grub or bootloaders in general. This system has UEFI, and Windows 8.1 is still installed on the harddisk. Ubuntu is installed on partition sda9, but it does not boot. When I remove the usb stick with the live install, Windows boots.

I followed these two guides:

- [How do I install Linux Mint 17 from USB on Flex 10?](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/How-do-I-install-Linux-Mint-17-from-USB-on-Flex-10/td-p/1589130): Cigydd answers his own question with 11 steps. I succeeded to step 7.
- [Ubuntu (or other Linux) on the Asus Transformer Book T100](http://www.jfwhome.com/2014/03/07/perfect-ubuntu-or-other-linux-on-the-asus-transformer-book-t100/): I started at step 4, and got stuck here.

See the **Ubuntu [Pastebin for Root-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7935303/)**

**Bounty**

I've put a 50 point bounty on this question, but haven't awarded it because the answers didn't help me any further. I will award 50 points again if an answer here helps me get this working.

**EFI firmware**

- The Flex 10 has a 32-bit efi firmware, which complicates things a bit.
- Following above guides, I've downloaded `bootia32.efi` and put it on the ubuntu stick in `/EFI/BOOT`.
- In the same folder I see two other files: `BOOTx64.EFI` and `grubx64.efi`.

**Problem**

I'm stuck in the second guide, step 4, with the following line:

```
linux (hd2,gpt5)/boot/vmlinuz-3.13-xxxx root=/dev/mmcblk0p5 video=VGA-1:1368x768e reboot=pci,force
```

The partition is hd2, gpt9 if I'm correct. Strangely enough, it seems I need to leave a space after the comma:

```
linux (hd2, gpt9)/boot/...
```

Using the live system, I found the vmlinuz version:

```
/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic.efi.signed
```

I don't know what to do with the `root=/dev/...` setting. Below you see the output for `ls -al /dev` for the installed partition.

```
root@ubuntu:/media/disk9# ls -al dev
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Apr 17 01:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root     4096 Jul 26 11:24 ..
crw-rw----  1 root video 10, 175 Apr 17 01:21 agpgart
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,   4 Apr 17 01:21 audio
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,  20 Apr 17 01:21 audio1
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,  36 Apr 17 01:21 audio2
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,  52 Apr 17 01:21 audio3
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,   7 Apr 17 01:21 audioctl
crw-------  1 root tty    5,   1 Apr 17 01:21 console
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       11 Jul 26 11:08 core -> /proc/kcore
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,   3 Apr 17 01:21 dsp
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,  19 Apr 17 01:21 dsp1
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,  35 Apr 17 01:21 dsp2
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,  51 Apr 17 01:21 dsp3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       13 Jul 26 11:08 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,   7 Apr 17 01:21 full
crw-rw----  1 root fuse  10, 229 Apr 17 01:22 fuse
crw-r-----  1 root kmem   1,   2 Apr 17 01:21 kmem
brw-rw----  1 root disk   7,   0 Apr 17 01:21 loop0
brw-rw----  1 root disk   7,   1 Apr 17 01:21 loop1
brw-rw----  1 root disk   7,   2 Apr 17 01:21 loop2
brw-rw----  1 root disk   7,   3 Apr 17 01:21 loop3
brw-rw----  1 root disk   7,   4 Apr 17 01:21 loop4
brw-rw----  1 root disk   7,   5 Apr 17 01:21 loop5
brw-rw----  1 root disk   7,   6 Apr 17 01:21 loop6
brw-rw----  1 root disk   7,   7 Apr 17 01:21 loop7
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Apr 17 01:26 mapper
crw-r-----  1 root kmem   1,   1 Apr 17 01:21 mem
crw-rw----  1 root audio 35,   0 Apr 17 01:21 midi0
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,   2 Apr 17 01:21 midi00
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,  18 Apr 17 01:21 midi01
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,  34 Apr 17 01:21 midi02
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,  50 Apr 17 01:21 midi03
crw-rw----  1 root audio 35,   1 Apr 17 01:21 midi1
crw-rw----  1 root audio 35,   2 Apr 17 01:21 midi2
crw-rw----  1 root audio 35,   3 Apr 17 01:21 midi3
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,   0 Apr 17 01:21 mixer
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,  16 Apr 17 01:21 mixer1
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,  32 Apr 17 01:21 mixer2
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,  48 Apr 17 01:21 mixer3
crw-rw----  1 root audio 31,   0 Apr 17 01:21 mpu401data
crw-rw----  1 root audio 31,   1 Apr 17 01:21 mpu401stat
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,   3 Apr 17 01:21 null
crw-r-----  1 root kmem   1,   4 Apr 17 01:21 port
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    5,   2 Feb 14 02:04 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Apr 17 01:21 pts
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4 Jul 26 11:08 ram -> ram1
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,   0 Apr 17 01:21 ram0
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,   1 Apr 17 01:21 ram1
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,  10 Apr 17 01:21 ram10
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,  11 Apr 17 01:21 ram11
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,  12 Apr 17 01:21 ram12
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,  13 Apr 17 01:21 ram13
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,  14 Apr 17 01:21 ram14
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,  15 Apr 17 01:21 ram15
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,  16 Apr 17 01:21 ram16
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,   2 Apr 17 01:21 ram2
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,   3 Apr 17 01:21 ram3
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,   4 Apr 17 01:21 ram4
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,   5 Apr 17 01:21 ram5
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,   6 Apr 17 01:21 ram6
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,   7 Apr 17 01:21 ram7
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,   8 Apr 17 01:21 ram8
brw-rw----  1 root disk   1,   9 Apr 17 01:21 ram9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,   8 Apr 17 01:21 random
crw-rw----  1 root audio 35,  64 Apr 17 01:21 rmidi0
crw-rw----  1 root audio 35,  65 Apr 17 01:21 rmidi1
crw-rw----  1 root audio 35,  66 Apr 17 01:21 rmidi2
crw-rw----  1 root audio 35,  67 Apr 17 01:21 rmidi3
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,   1 Apr 17 01:21 sequencer
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        8 Jul 26 11:08 shm -> /run/shm
crw-rw----  1 root audio 35, 128 Apr 17 01:21 smpte0
crw-rw----  1 root audio 35, 129 Apr 17 01:21 smpte1
crw-rw----  1 root audio 35, 130 Apr 17 01:21 smpte2
crw-rw----  1 root audio 35, 131 Apr 17 01:21 smpte3
crw-rw----  1 root audio 14,   6 Apr 17 01:21 sndstat
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4 Jul 26 11:08 stderr -> fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4 Jul 26 11:08 stdin -> fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4 Jul 26 11:08 stdout -> fd/1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    5,   0 Apr 17 01:21 tty
crw-------  1 root tty    4,   0 Apr 17 01:21 tty0
crw-------  1 root tty    4,   1 Apr 17 01:21 tty1
crw-------  1 root tty    4,   2 Apr 17 01:21 tty2
crw-------  1 root tty    4,   3 Apr 17 01:21 tty3
crw-------  1 root tty    4,   4 Apr 17 01:21 tty4
crw-------  1 root tty    4,   5 Apr 17 01:21 tty5
crw-------  1 root tty    4,   6 Apr 17 01:21 tty6
crw-------  1 root tty    4,   7 Apr 17 01:21 tty7
crw-------  1 root tty    4,   8 Apr 17 01:21 tty8
crw-------  1 root tty    4,   9 Apr 17 01:21 tty9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,   9 Apr 17 01:21 urandom
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,   5 Apr 17 01:21 zero
```

This would result in the following command for grub:

```
linux (hd2, gpt9)/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=/dev/????? video=VGA-1:1366x768e reboot=pci,force
```

**Output for `cat /proc/partitions` as requested by user309427**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   7        0     944156 loop0
   8        0  312571224 sda
   8        1    1024000 sda1
   8        2     266240 sda2
   8        3     131072 sda3
   8        4  148405248 sda4
   8        5     460800 sda5
   8        6   26214400 sda6
   8        7   13188096 sda7
   8        8    3999744 sda8
   8        9   24414208 sda9
   8       10   94466048 sda10
   8       16    1957888 sdb
   8       17    1956864 sdb1
```

**Output for `mount` as requested by user309427**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mount
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu)
```

**Output for `blkid` as requested by Bain**

- Ubuntu is installed on sda9, and sda10 is the home partition.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo su
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="WINRE_DRV" UUID="CE4A98414A98286B" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="SYSTEM_DRV" UUID="329B-10F9" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="C28CCB398CCB26AF" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="70601C2E601BFA14" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="LENOVO" UUID="48B255E5B255D7D0" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda7: LABEL="PBR_DRV" UUID="6A72A04272A014BB" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda9: UUID="673b6434-a5f0-49f0-8a01-af6894958777" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda10: UUID="dd7b47a9-33bf-4b73-a880-6e7e488e9c79" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="UBUNTU 14_0" UUID="1C9C-CB71" TYPE="vfat"
```

**Questions**

- What setting should I use for the root setting?

The screen resolution of my system is 1366x768, not 1368x768.

- What is the setting for the video?
- Besides all this, is this the way to get grub working properly?
- Maybe I misunderstand, but I read I should copy `bootia32.efi` to the disk. To what folder? I don't see an EFI folder in the root of the installed system.

Comment: Btw, I just noticed the little detail about the Flex 10 having a 32-bit efi firmware; so I deleted my answer, which wouldn't apply. ;)

Comment: Yes that's true. Good that you mention it. I added it to the question.

Comment: According to the 2nd link, 14.10 will support 32-bit efi. In the meantime, you might be able to install to an external usb drive using legacy mode. Not the best solution (if it works), but it might get you by until the problem is solved.

Comment: Why did you start following the second guide from the beginning? The first guide applies to your hardware and describes exactly what you want to do. Since you already have Ubuntu installed, just begin from step 6 - boot linux from hard drive using the iso, then just compile and install grub using the instructions from "6. Completing the installation". You do not need to manually set the grub command line.

Comment: @bain, I didn't start the second guide from the beginning - and I should clarify that in the question. I started at step 4, then got stuck immediately.

Comment: You need to know which partition you installed Ubuntu to. Can you boot from the USB drive and do `blkid` and paste the output here.

Comment: I've updated the question with the output from `blkid`.

Comment: Do I need to copy the EFI file to the harddisk? If so, where should it go? I don't see an EFI folder in the root.

Comment: Before doing the manual work, did you try to run `boot-repair` from the live environment?

Comment: It won't install on Ubuntu 14.04. I've tried Supergrub as well - no success. I can try this with Ubuntu 12.04. If that works, I can upgrade to 14.04 later.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, see http://paste.ubuntu.com/7935303/

Comment: I installed a new harddisk, reinstalled ubuntu, but no change. I tried boot-repair - didn't help. I tried to install rEFInd. I don't know if I did that correctly, on the live install, but since then I get the message: `Windows Boot Manager boot failed`. It seems like something changed, but still no boot.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, first order of business problably would be finding the root device. I've never seen the naming you seem to be having. Can you give the output of

> cat /proc/partitions

and

> mount

That will probably help getting the root partition's name.

Since EFI boot comes with its own bag of troubles, would you accept a solution wherein you install the grub bootloader on your linux partition (so not MBR or anything) and chainboot from the Windows Loader into grub via Windows Loader Menu? If so, what you'd need to do is install grub into the current linux root partition, copy the first 512 bytes out via dd into a file and copy that file over to Windows' system drive. From there it's a few commands for the bcd (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721886%28v=ws.10%29.aspx ) to add the grub bootloader now in a file to the Windows startup list, although I've never done it on an EFI system.

Comment: If I can get Linux to boot directly, that is good enough. It's OK to ditch MBR if it's still possible to startup Windows. Is there a risk involved and can I go back?

Comment: Unless you misuse bsdedit on Windows side and destroy your boot configuration there shouldn't be any. And yes it's undoable.
Basically follow these steps: http://alien.slackbook.org/blog/adding-linux-to-the-windows7-boot-menu/ (Yes they are for Windows 7 but should work the same)

Comment: I've added the requested output to my question for the root partition name.